# Javascript function returning undefined for template helper

Tags: javascript, jquery

Creating a template helper to return a variable to be displayed in the DOM, and my function is returning undefined and thus is not affecting the DOM. Not exactly sure why, though I feel as if it is a binding issue. Here's the code:

```
supportNumber: function(){
            var jobSupportNumber = state.user.jobs.each(function(job){
                console.log(jobOrder.get("jobId"));
                console.log("test");
                console.log(job.get("id"));
                if(jobOrder.get("jobId") == job.get("id")){
                    var jobNumber = job.get("supportNumber");
                    console.log(jobNumber);
                    return jobNumber;
                } 
                else{
                    console.log("this fired");
                }
            });
            console.log(jobSupportNumber);
            return jobSupportNumber;
}
```

I'm console logging alot to make sure values are being returned, and something is being returned all the way up until the final return statement, which returns jobSupportNumber as undefined. What am I doing wrong to have it return always as undefined?

Comment: Your `state.user.jobs.each()` apparently is not returning anything. What do you expect `jobSupportNumber` to be?

Comment: It should returning the jobNumber, which I know has a value since the console log before the return gives me what I want.

Comment: You have an additional "return" in the function, is that causing it?

Comment: supportNumber: function() {
    var jobSupportNumber;
    state.user.jobs.forEach(function(job) {
        if(jobOrder.get("jobId") === job.get("id")) {
            jobSupportNumber = job.get("supportNumber");
        }
    });

    return jobSupportNumber;
};

Comment: you can't return a value from within your 'each' loop. just assign it to a variable and then return that variable. see my other comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.each()` doesn't return the value of any of the function it's wrapping.  The inner function results are only used to control the `.each()` loop.

Try this:

```
supportNumber: function(){
  var jobSupportNumber = null;

  state.user.jobs.each(function(job){
   if(jobOrder.get("jobId") == job.get("id")){
     jobSupportNumber = job.get("supportNumber");
     return false;  // tell .each() to quit looping
   } 
  });

  return jobSupportNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the code you have there, `state.user.jobs.each()` is *not* going to return `jobNumber`. That return applies to your anonymous function. (where you have `function(job)`.

To get that value, you want something more like this:

```
supportNumber: function(){
    var jobSupportNumber;
    state.user.jobs.each(function(job){
    console.log(jobOrder.get("jobId"));
    console.log("test");
    console.log(job.get("id"));
    if(jobOrder.get("jobId") == job.get("id")){
        var jobNumber = job.get("supportNumber");
        console.log(jobNumber);
        /* Set the value and just plain return, instead */
        jobSupportNumber = jobNumber;
        return;
    } 
    else{
        console.log("this fired");
    }
});
console.log(jobSupportNumber);
return jobSupportNumber;
}
```